# How to detect if service from other app is working?

Tags: android

I have for example 20 apps:

1. app1
2. app2
3. app20

Each of this app have background service. I need to somehow detect from other apps if service in app number x is working and then make action to not run it from other apps. If app number x is going to be uninstalled, then run service from next app.
Times to run service are different, one starts at 8:01, second 8:07, depends to install time.

I tried with package manager and shared prefs(single app). Each solution give me results:

- service is running only from initiator app
- service will not run anywhere
- service will run everywhere x20 ;/

Any possible solution?

- i can't use shared preferences between apps, package name is not constant, i cannot put the list of packages and access to each app
- though about server, json file changing by service and restoring by cron jobs when service need to be restored
- maybe some SD card file? (problem is that every android device have different path to SD) and what if app what created service will be deleted by user?